# Using array values in mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, file, mysqli

I am reading the database connectivity credentials from a file and storing it in an array .I want to use the values in the array, inside mysql_connect().but i am getting a warning  and its not connecting:

> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in A:\xamppnew\htdocs\mdb_display.php on line 13
> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in A:\xamppnew\htdocs\mdb_display.php on line 13

Here is my code

```
    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("db_con.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $db_cred="";
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $db_cred[]= fgets($myfile) ;
       }
    fclose($myfile);


    $con = mysqli_connect($db_cred[0],$db_cred[1],$db_cred[2],$db_cred[3]);

 $var="select ulastdatetime from userattedancelog where orgid=1 ";
 $result = $con->query($var);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 echo $row["ulastdatetime"];
 $dat='#'. $row["ulastdatetime"].'#';

 //closing databse connection
 $con->close();
 ?>
```

How can i use the values in array in the mysql_connect .

Comment: Start with `print_r($db_cred);`

Comment: Title i̶s̶ was misleading, you are using `mysqli_connect` not `mysql_connect`.

Comment: print_r($db_cred); is working..Its reading from file and i am able to print it too.. instead of array values if i insert the original values itself in mysql_connect ,then it works. But i want it this way, to read from file and use them to connect.

Comment: @Script47 I am sorry i didnt get you

Comment: replace `mysqli_connect` to `mysqli` and see if it works !

Comment: Thankyou for the comments. ts solved now

Comment: Why are you initialising `$db_creds` as a string and then treat it like an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trim your data after `gets` so that extra new line space can be removed

```
$myfile = fopen("db_con.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $db_cred=array();
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $db_cred[]= trim(fgets($myfile)); //<------------trim data
       }
    fclose($myfile);


    $con = mysqli_connect($db_cred[0],$db_cred[1],$db_cred[2],$db_cred[3]);

 $var="select ulastdatetime from userattedancelog where orgid=1 ";
 $result = $con->query($var);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 echo $row["ulastdatetime"];
 $dat='#'. $row["ulastdatetime"].'#';

 //closing databse connection
 $con->close();
```